# How to recursively call another function repeatedly in sml?

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj

> I have a function called mergeP:

```
fun mergeP(nil) = nil
| mergeP(x::[]) = x::[]
| mergeP(x::y::zs) = (x @ y)::mergeP(zs);
```

> If `mergeP` is called like:  `mergeP([[1],[2],[3],[4]])` it will
>   return `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. I want to create a function called `mergeS`
>   that is recursive that repeatedly calls `mergeP` till the sublist
>   equals just one list. So if `mergeS` were called like:
>   `mergeS([[1],[2],[3],[4]])` it would repeatedly call `mergeP` till it
>   equals: `[1,2,3,4]`. Here is my try:

```
- fun mergeS(nil) = nil
= |mergeS(xs) = mergeS(mergeP(xs));
```

> But this gives me the error:

```
stdIn:6.1-6.26 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
val it = [] : ?.X1 list
```

Comment: I don't think you can define a function that "removes" an arbitrary number of list nesting levels in SML's type system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe I got it to work:

```
fun mergeS(nil) = nil
| mergeS([xs]) = xs
| mergeS(xs) = mergeS(mergeP(xs));
```

Comment: Yes, that does work. It is satisfying when you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works nicely, though it is possible to skip `mergeP` and define `mergeS` directly:

```
fun mergeS [] = []
|   mergeS ([]::xss) = mergeS xss
|   mergeS ((x::xs)::xss) = x :: mergeS (xs::xss);
```

In the third line, the function recursively pulls off the elements in the first inner list and tacks them onto the final result. When there is nothing more in this first list to pull off, you are done with it, and the second line throws it away and moves on to process the rest of the inner lists. When there are no more inner lists to process, you hit the basis case in line 1 and are done.

This function that you are calling `mergeS` would be more idiomatically called `flatten` since it "flattens" a list of lists into a single list. This flattens a single level. You could also write a function which flattens e.g. two levels (lists of lists of lists to single lists), but, as @molbdnilo points out in the comments, it isn't possible in SML to write a function which can flatten nested lists to arbitrary levels of nesting. You can't write a function which e.g. will work with `[[[1,2]],[[3],[4]]]` as well as `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` since SML's type system has no type constructor which corresponds to arbitrarily nested lists.